# How can I bring user=pk in this case? I want to list on the basis of user's location

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to bring the user=pk in the 3rd line which is commented. I have no issue with changing the class to APIview from ListAPIview. How can I implement pk in this case? I tried writing a def get but was not able to call the customer.location.

```
class ServiceProviderList(generics.ListAPIView):
    # customer = CustomerProfile.objects.get(user=3)
    # queryset = ProfileCompletion.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(customer.location,25))#all().order_by('-id')
    queryset = ProfileCompletion.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ProfilecompletioneSerializer
    filterset_class=SnippetFilter
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter,OrderingFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['fullname', 'category','departments','services']
    search_fields = ['fullname', 'category__name','departments__dept_name','services__service_name']
```

Comment: Your `CustomerProfile` has a `location`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the `get_queryset` method:

```
class ServiceProviderList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = ProfileCompletion.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ProfilecompletioneSerializer
    filterset_class=SnippetFilter
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter,OrderingFilter]
    filterset_fields = ['fullname', 'category','departments','services']
    search_fields = ['fullname', 'category__name','departments__dept_name','services__service_name']

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        customer = CustomerProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs):
        return qs.filter(
            location__distance_lte=(customer.location,25)
        ).order_by('-id')
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, How can I filter the list by 25 km of radius? 
Getting this error.
"Only numeric values of degree units are allowed on geodetic distance queries."

Answer (score 0):

@Surya,
Good afternoon. One of the ways is to implement the Primary Key based operations. Many thanks.

```
class EmployeeDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
```